# w3wp exception using site under IIS

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015

Using a site deployed on local IIS with Visual Studio attached in debug or not I often face the following problem (sorry for Italian localization):

[image: Error]

Translation:

> An unhandled Microsoft .Net Framework exception occured in w3wp.exe
>   [8776].
>
> The Just-In-Time debugger was launched without necessary security
>   permissions. To debug this proces, the JIT debugger must be run as an
>   administrator. Would you like to debug the process?

The same problem appear randomly when I change assemblies or other files in the site folder (bin or web.config).

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, but the problem happens on Visual Studio 2013 update 4 too.

Comment: It would be helpful for future readers if you could provide an English translation of the dialog box.

Comment: In the meanwhile I changed the laptop third times and some other VS versions came out

Answer (score 1):

You need to be running VS in administrator mode in order to attach to the W3WP process. You can either restart when attaching (as I believe it's prompting you to do), or just always run in admin mode to start with.

If you *are* running as administrator, then it's possible that something in your app is crashing the process when the app is loaded. I'd consider:

- Checking the Event Viewer for any telltale errors/exceptions
- Rolling back recent changes to see if the problem disappears
- Creating a small shell app that doesn't do much to see if you can run and attach to that OK, to rule out machine/IIS/environment issues.

Comment: I'm running Visual Studio as administrator